# Pulling Variable out of an Array

Tags: php

I am trying to pull a variable out of an array with name of variable coming from another variable.

I have tried both: `$get_results[$name]` and `$get_results->$name` with no success.

I keep on getting following error on `$get_results[$name]`: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in 
But on `$get_results->$name` it skips over it.

The `$name` is loaded by user.
The `$get_results` is loaded by MYSQL database

```php
$name = 'test2'
$get_results = array('test' - > '1', 'test2' - > '2');

if (!isset($get_results[$name])) {
  if (empty($get_results[$name])) {
    $value = $get_results[$name];
  } else {
    $value = "";
  }
}
elseif(!isset($_POST[$name])) {
  $value = Input::get($name);
} else {
  $value = "";
}
```

I am trying to get the value from $get_results from test2.

---

I have made the changes to my script:

```
    if(isset($get_results[$name])){
        if(!empty($get_results[$name])){
            $value = $get_results[$name];
        } else {
            $value = "";
        }
    }elseif(!isset($_POST[$name])){
        $value = Input::get($name);
    }else {
        $value = "";
    }
```

When I try to pull the data from `$get_results[$name]` its dies with error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

[image: This shows the <code>$get_results</code> and <code>$name</code> loaded with variables.]
[image: Error 1]
[image: Error 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**your get_results variable returns an object**

use this:

```
get_results->$name;
```

Comment: It fixed the issue.
Thank You

Answer (score 3):

You are running into a syntax error while initializing your array. Associative array uses `=>` rather than `->`.

So, just replace

```
$get_results = array ('test' -> '1', 'test2' -> '2');
```

with

```
$get_results = array ('test' => '1', 'test2' => '2');
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have a syntax error in array creation update `->` to `=>`.

do

```
$name = 'test2';
$get_results = array ('test' => '1', 'test2' => '2');
echo 'value will be : '.$get_results[$name];die;
```

Output:

```
value will be : 2
```

Second you have logic error too in if
Please check below corrected code

```
$name = 'test2';
$get_results = array('test' => '1', 'test2' => '2');
if (isset($get_results[$name])) {//check if $name is in array will true
    if (!empty($get_results[$name])) {//check if $name in array is not empty
        $value = $get_results[$name];
    } else {
        $value = "test 1";
    }
} elseif (!isset($_POST[$name])) {
    $value = "test 2";//Input::get($name);
} else {
    $value = "test 3";
}
echo 'value will be : '.$value;die;
```

Output:

```
value will be : 2
```